# Sub-setting by partial date r

Tags: r, date, subset

I am trying to find a way to subset a data.frame to only the records from a single month, but over multiple years (i.e. data from only April but years 1900, 1901, 1902, etc.).  I am putting the date information into a date class using the as.Date function.  Here is an example:

```
require("adehabitatHR")
data(teal)
Tdf <- teal
Tdf$date <- as.Date(Tdf$date, "%Y%m%d")
```

Now to subset it, I have tried setting the date equal to the month value both with and without using wildcards:

```
TdfFeb <- Tdf[Tdf$date == "*-02-*"]
TdfFeb <- Tdf[Tdf$date == "-02-"]
```

However, in both these situations I receive an error of: Error in charToDate(x): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format; this would suggest that R is not recognizing what I am inputting as a legitimate date format (I have also tried this with "/" and "." as opposed to "-"; all with the same outcome.

I have also tried setting it as a pattern

```
TdfFeb <- Tdf[Tdf$date == pattern = "-02-"]
```

Of course this does not work either, with an error due to the unexpected "=" after pattern.

I realize that for this particular data set, simply doing a date range would work since there is only data for February in 1901; however, as I said above, I would like to be able to pull out data over multiple years this way.  If anyone has encountered this before or has a suggestion I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Try the `lubridate` package which has a function `month()` that will return the month from a date object as an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a valid date, you can extract the month using `format`.

```
month <- format(Tdf$date, format = "%m")

Tdf[month == "02", ]

               x        y       date
55851  5.9153319 45.44334 1901-02-01
57834  3.3944621 42.64384 1901-02-01
1917   9.9942731 43.42349 1901-02-01
58703  0.7046530 39.45739 1901-02-01
5673   3.2158674 41.60035 1901-02-01
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using something like `format`:

```
format(Tdf$date, '%m') == '02'
```

The problem with your approach is that `==` is overloaded for `Date`s, and internally R is trying to convert `-02-` to a `Date` before comparing with `Tdf$date`. Of course `-02-` by itself doesn't correspond to any date. The format approach converts your `Date` to `character` first before comparison.

A couple of packages (e.g. `lubridate`, `data.table`) have the helper function `month` which will return a numeric (specifically, in the case of `data.table`, `integer`) `2` which allows a similar but perhaps more readable approach:

```
data.table::month(Tdf$date) == 2L
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is combining `lubridate::month`, and `dplyr::mutate` / `dplyr::filter`:

```
library("adehabitatHR")
data(teal)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
# Change column to date and create month column
teal <- mutate(teal, 
               date = ymd_hms(date), 
               month = month(date))

# Filter for month 
teal %>% filter(month == 2)
          x        y                date month
1  5.915332 45.44334 1901-02-01 00:29:11     2
2  3.394462 42.64384 1901-02-01 05:51:41     2
3  9.994273 43.42349 1901-02-01 07:06:29     2
4  0.704653 39.45739 1901-02-01 10:03:25     2
5  3.215867 41.60035 1901-02-01 12:54:33     2
6  3.275865 43.58711 1901-02-02 00:07:21     2
7  4.723084 43.49749 1901-02-02 06:53:26     2
8  1.760862 41.37676 1901-02-02 07:01:53     2
9  5.814787 41.64366 1901-02-02 13:59:14     2
10 2.435756 48.94306 1901-02-02 16:04:14     2
...
```